# JsonReaderException was unhandled

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to parse JSON in C#. I also tried the way that I found on stack overflow.

The JSON data of my service is like this:

```
[
    { 
        "CamsPassword":"abc",
        "CamsUserName":"123"
    },
    {
        "CamsPassword":"pucit",
        "CamsUserName":"556"
    }
]
```

The post that I have found on stack overflow had different JSON format. I followed that code but getting exception and unable to resolve it.

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace in my project. It says `Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: ". Path '[1]', line 8, position 15`.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\test.json");

    var objects = JArray.Parse(json); // parse as array  
    foreach (JObject root in objects)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> app in root)
        {

            var pass = (String)app.Value["CamsPassword"];
            var un = (String)app.Value["CamsUserName"];

            Console.WriteLine(pass);
            Console.WriteLine(un);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code?

Comment: @JimAho it breaks at var object = JArray.Parse(json);

Comment: Passwords in cleartext? No good idea...

Comment: @RabiaMehmood Inspect the value of `json` before running `JArray.Parse(json);`. It might not be what you thought.

Comment: you should not parse into objects. Let Json.Net do the work and `DeSerialize` directly into your class/array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DrKoch said in comment, why not use the `Deserialize` method from Json.Net ?

[Working Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1fNVnw)

You need an Object

```
public class CamsObject
{
    public string CamsPassword { get; set; }
    public string CamsUserName { get; set; }
}
```

And let's go :

```
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\test.json");
var camsObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CamsObject[]>(json);
```